# Why does getAllPermissions() only return one permission?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-permission

Using Laravel with `Auth` and [Spatie\laravel-permission](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission) packages. I have a User with the **Admin Role**. Several other **Permissions** are also attached to this **Role**.

I noticed `'can:permission_name'` and `'permission:permission_name'` middlewares weren't functioning properly, so I started debugging. I realized that `$user->getAllPermissions()` only returns the permission with the highest `id`. In addition, when running `$user->hasPermissionTo()` on other permissions than the one previously mentioned, it returns false.

I would really appreciate the help. Also, I have tried to clear the cache as well.

Seeder function:

```
public function run() {
    $permissions[0] = Permission::create(['guard_name' => 'web', 'name' => 'Access Admin Panel']);
    $permissions[1] = Permission::create(['guard_name' => 'web', 'name' => 'Access Music']);
    $permissions[2] = Permission::create(['guard_name' => 'web', 'name' => 'Edit Database']);
    $permissions[3] = Permission::create(['guard_name' => 'web', 'name' => 'Login']);


    $role[0] = Role::create(['guard_name' => 'web', 'name' => 'Administrator']);
    $role[0]->permissions()->attach($permissions[0]);
    $role[0]->permissions()->attach($permissions[1]);
    $role[0]->permissions()->attach($permissions[2]);
    $role[0]->permissions()->attach($permissions[3]);

    $role[1] = Role::create(['guard_name' => 'web', 'name' => 'VIP']);
    $role[1]->permissions()->attach($permissions[1]);
    $role[1]->permissions()->attach($permissions[2]);
    $role[1]->permissions()->attach($permissions[3]);

    $role[2] = Role::create(['guard_name' => 'web', 'name' => 'Trusted']);
    $role[2]->permissions()->attach($permissions[2]);
    $role[2]->permissions()->attach($permissions[3]);

    $role[3] = Role::create(['guard_name' => 'web', 'name' => 'User']);
    $role[3]->permissions()->attach($permissions[3]);

    $role[4] = Role::create(['guard_name' => 'web', 'name' => 'Disabled']);


    $admin = User::create(['name' => 'Gandalfsdottir', 'email' => 'my@email.com', 'password' => Hash::make('demo')]);
    $admin->markEmailAsVerified();
    $admin->assignRole('Administrator');

    $demo = User::create(['name' => 'Demo', 'email' => 'my@secondemail.fr', 'password' => Hash::make('demo')]);
    $demo->markEmailAsVerified();
    $demo->assignRole('User');
}
```

Comment: Did you properly assign all those roles you are looking for?

Comment: It certainly looks to be right in the database: all the records are there. I have put my seeder function on the question.

Comment: Let me reproduce this on my machine

Comment: How did you clear the cache? Did you do it with `php artisan permission:cache-reset`?

Comment: @Clean code: Thank you for taking the time! 

@Remul: I usually do `php artisan optimize:clear`, but I tried yours and it made no difference.

Comment: I identified the issue and its related to the repository. Here's the link to the actual issue on [Github](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission/issues/1531)

Comment: Oh thanks, good job! I still wonder though, why I do get one returned value. And how come this is an issue on a so widely used package/function?

Comment: I see the issue's been closed, loooks like the problem is in our environment.